# Batch Generator function returns only last element when converted to list

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator, yield

I have the following code to generate batches from a list of items:

```
def batch_generator(items, batch_size):
    count = 1
    chunk = []
    
    for item in items:
        if count % batch_size:
            chunk.append(item)
        else:
            chunk.append(item)
            yield chunk
            chunk.clear()
        count += 1
    
    if len(chunk):
        yield chunk
```

Iterating one-by-one yields expected results:

```
for x in batch_generator(range(17), 5):
    print(x)
# [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
# [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
# [10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
# [15, 16]
```

However when I convert generator to a list directly, only the last element is returned, multiple times!

```
list(batch_generator(range(17), 5))
# [[15, 16], [15, 16], [15, 16], [15, 16]]
```

Whereas a simple generator converted to list works just fine:

```
list(([i,i*2,i*3] for i in range(5)))
# [[0, 0, 0], [1, 2, 3], [2, 4, 6], [3, 6, 9], [4, 8, 12]]
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: You yield the same list object (chunk) in your generator every time, when you iterate over it you print the objects current contents but when you convert to a list you just have multiple references to the same list. You should create an empty list rather than clearing and reusing the same list

Comment: You are returning the same object and `chunk.clear()` mutates the object in-place hence the changes are reflected in all the lists. Use `chunk = []` instead of .clear should give you intended results. In for loop with print, it looked like it worked as expected but it did not. Had you stored them in a container you would observe all lists would be the same. Try this list comprehension `out = [print(x) or x for x  in batch_generator(range(17), 5)]; print(out)` The print statement inside prints correct values but `out` would have same values inside it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`chunk.clear()` is the problem here. At the end of the day the list returned is the same list returned multiple times.

replace `chunk.clear()` with `chunk = []`. That way `chunk` will be different instances of a list:

Answer (score 1):

You can yield a copy of chunk with `chunk[:]` or `list(chunk)`. Instead of just `yield chunk`.